# Design Techniques to Defend Against the Pitfalls of Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, refactoring

**Summary**

I relied on the compiler to point to every location in my code I would need to update while changing the signature of a member function in a parent class, but the compiler failed to point out an overridden instance of that function in a child class, causing a logical error in my program. I would like to re-implement the classes so that I can rely more on the compiler while making changes of this kind.

**Details via an example**

I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
    virtual void bar();
}

class B: public A
{
public:
    void bar();
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
void A:foo(){ ... bar(); ... }
void A:bar(){ ... }
void B:bar(){ ... }
```

Note that whhen I call b->foo() (where b has type B* and B is a subclass of A) the bar() method called is B:bar()

After changing the type-signature of A:bar(), to say A:bar(*some_parameter*), my code looked like this:

```
void A:foo(){ ... bar(param); ... }
void A:bar(param) { ... }
void B:bar(){ ... }
```

Now, when I call b->foo(), of course A:bar(param) is called. I expected such a case to be caught by the compiler, but I realize now that it cannot.

How would I implement classes A & B to avoid bugs of this class.

Comment: @Jarod42 No, in the legacy code I am dealing with bar() is not virtual.

Comment: So, this [Example](http://ideone.com/nfh5HF) shows that your first hypothesis is wrong, `A::bar()` is called and not `B::bar()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My mistake: A:bar() is declared virtual, but I suppose its not a pure virtual. I will fix the original example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to detect this issue in c++03 where it did not have yet the `override` specifier (It is since c++11 standard) is to do pure virtual method in an interface. If you change the sign of a pure virtual method, all its subclasses must change it too or they will not compile.

Do not depend on concrete classes. Depend on interfaces. You will do better designs.

Your design would change to something like this:

```
class IA
{
public:
    void foo() { ... bar(); ...}
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~IA() {}
};
class A : public IA
{
public:
    void bar() {...}
};
class B : public IA
{
public:
    void bar() {...}
};
```

Now, if you change the sign of bar in the interface, all its subclasses must change it too.

Comment: This indicates that there's a difference between C++ and C++11- which there isn't, except to say that C++ is now 14 which includes `override`.

Comment: @Puppy Maybe I did not explain rightly. I suggested a different solution to detect this kind of problem in compilation time in C++03 . I did it because he did not specified to do it in C++11 or 14.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected such a case to be caught by the compiler, but I realize now
>   that it cannot do so.

Actually, it can do so. You can use `override` on `B::bar`'s declaration, and the compiler will error if there is no suitable base class function for it to override.

Comment: Hmm... that *would* work if the function were virtual.

Comment: I agree with Puppy. I recently fixed a bug that had been plaguing me by explicitly adding the `override` attribute, and the compiler flagged it.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Well, the question text doesn't match its own code.  According to the question, the author had "an overridden instance of that function"... and yes, that must be `virtual`.